# How to find the reason which cause Postgres CPU Utilization steep increase?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ip, rds

Every UTC 0:00,the aws Postgres RDS instance has a cpu utilizaiton steep increase.

[image]

Our backend program doesn't have a scheduled task at this time.There was no sudden request at this time either。the `DB Connections`,`Free Storage Space`,`Freeable Memory`,`Write IOPS`,`Read IOPS` are all in normal level.

and I have used

`SELECT pid, age(query_start, clock_timestamp()), usename, query,state 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE query != '<IDLE>' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%' 
ORDER BY query_start desc;`

to find some exception queries,but there is not any slow query.

so,where should I look for reasons?

Comment: I would ask the service provider. For example, when and how are database backups performed?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for your scheduled processes(either its backup or some db\application jobs) or try enabling log_min_duration_statement parameter in PostgreSQL.conf file to track any bad query.